Jasper: Generate design tab from source rather than studio/editor
Editing a .jrxml file from your favorite IDE (in my case VSCode) instead of JaspersoftStudio how to make the Design tab update as soon as I save the changes without having to replicate it in the Source tab in JasperStudio ?
Is there a way to generate the equivalent of the design tab output from a jrxml file out of JasperStudio ?
